# ¿Como puedo crear una lista (refiriendome a la estructura de datos) en Python a partir de este archivo CSV?

Tags: python, lista, csv

> Este es mi archivo CSV:

```
Titulo1   TItulo2  Titulo3 
one        two     three
A          B       C
```

> Mi código Python:

```
texto = open('Example.csv', 'r')
listaInt = []
variable = texto.readlines()
lista = list(variable.split(',')) 
listaInt.sort()  
print(listaInt)
```

Comment: ¿Qué elementos ha de tener tu lista? Ya que una tabla CSV es en el fondo bidimensional (pues tiene filas y columnas), tu lista debería reproducir esta estructura. Por ejemplo, sería una lista cuyos elementos sean las filas, que son a su vez otras listas cuyos elementos son ya los valores de cada celda.

Comment: Supongamos que el programa que quiero desarrollar debe hacer lo siguiente: ya poseo mi archivo CSV (La estructura Bidimensional), sin embargo quiero que mi programa python lo lea, después de ello, Ubique el elemento uno, dos y tres de la fila tres, (LETRAS A, B y C) para que realize cierta operación, distinta para cada uno de los casos , es decir que por ejemplo cuando encuentre A realice una suma con otro archivo de entrada que voy a darle, cuando encuentre a B realice una suma del mismo modo con los recursos de un archivo externo al proyecto, Gracias Saludos espero me puedas ayudar :D

Answer (score 0):

Tal vez esto sirva:

```
import csv

with open('ruta_del_archivo.csv', 'r') as archivo:
    leer = csv.reader(archivo)
    lista = list(leer)
    print(lista)
```

Otra forma de hacerlo sería:

```
lista = []
archivo = open('ruta_archivo.csv', 'r')

for line in archivo:
    lista.append(line.strip().split(','))

lista
```

Answer (score 0):

Intenta esto:

```
import csv

with open('file.csv', 'r') as f:
  reader = csv.reader(f)
  your_list = list(reader)

print(your_list)
```

Comment: Considera hacer el [tour] y agregar una breve explicación de tu código.